# Which sentence is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

- Monetary market intelligent prediction system.
- Intelligent Monetary market prediction system.

Description: This prediction system is an intelligent system.

Comment: They are not "sentences" but noun-phrases.  I suppose there could be stupid prediction systems that simply choose at random or don't learn from their mistakes, but the word **intelligent** is not really necessary, nor is it especially apt, since it is so general; it doesn't indicate the kind of intelligence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sentence is the correct one.

It is an:

> Intelligent (monetary market prediction system)

It isn't a:

> Monetary market (intelligent prediction system)

That is, it makes intelligent predictions about the monetary market. The first sentence is incorrect because "monetary market" isn't an adjective, it's part of the set of [noun modifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) that modify "system" along with "prediction."

As a rule, noun modifiers appear immediately beside the noun they modify (e.g. a *blue carving knife*, not a *carving blue knife*).

You could, however, say that it is an:

> Intelligent prediction system **for** the monetary market.